# Next.js - Application error: a client-side exception has occurred

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am implementing [this api](https://dokumentacja-inpost.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/PL/pages/7438409/Geowidget+v4+User+s+Guide+New).

Locally works fine. However when I deploy it to the production/test environment I get

```
Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).
```

And in console.log:

```
framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:4767 ReferenceError: easyPack is not defined
    at a.value (checkout-fb900c0cafcfc3f61693.js:1)
    at a.value (checkout-fb900c0cafcfc3f61693.js:1)
    at hu (framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:4977)
    at Li (framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:6115)
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:7861)
    at Wl (framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:2501)
    at Ti (framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:5904)
    at vi (framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:5619)
    at fi (framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:5411)
    at Gi (framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:6518)
uu @ framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:4767
a.componentDidCatch.n.callback @ framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:4901
fa @ framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:2780
hu @ framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:4979
Li @ framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:6115
t.unstable_runWithPriority @ framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:7861
Wl @ framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:2501
Ti @ framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:5904
vi @ framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:5619
(anonymous) @ framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:2525
t.unstable_runWithPriority @ framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:7861
Wl @ framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:2501
Ql @ framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:2521
Hl @ framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:2513
yi @ framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:5641
rs @ framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:6590
t.hydrate @ framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:7081
f.default.createElement.callbacks @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
ge @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
l @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
k @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
i @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
ce @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
se @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
l @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
k @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
i @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
Promise.then (async)
k @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
i @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
Promise.then (async)
k @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
i @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
Promise.then (async)
k @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
i @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
ue @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
t.initNext @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
457 @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
n @ webpack-adf3ef2afee18f8d2ced.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
n.O @ webpack-adf3ef2afee18f8d2ced.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
t @ webpack-adf3ef2afee18f8d2ced.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
Show 5 more frames


main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1 ReferenceError: easyPack is not defined
    at a.value (checkout-fb900c0cafcfc3f61693.js:1)
    at a.value (checkout-fb900c0cafcfc3f61693.js:1)
    at hu (framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:4977)
    at Li (framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:6115)
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:7861)
    at Wl (framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:2501)
    at Ti (framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:5904)
    at vi (framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:5619)
    at fi (framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:5411)
    at Gi (framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:6518)
le @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
fn @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
value @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
a.componentDidCatch.n.callback @ framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:4903
fa @ framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:2780
hu @ framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:4979
Li @ framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:6115
t.unstable_runWithPriority @ framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:7861
Wl @ framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:2501
Ti @ framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:5904
vi @ framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:5619
(anonymous) @ framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:2525
t.unstable_runWithPriority @ framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:7861
Wl @ framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:2501
Ql @ framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:2521
Hl @ framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:2513
yi @ framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:5641
rs @ framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:6590
t.hydrate @ framework-c93ed74a065331c4bd75.js:formatted:7081
f.default.createElement.callbacks @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
ge @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
l @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
k @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
i @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
ce @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
se @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
l @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
k @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
i @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
Promise.then (async)
k @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
i @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
Promise.then (async)
k @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
i @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
Promise.then (async)
k @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
i @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
ue @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
t.initNext @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
457 @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
n @ webpack-adf3ef2afee18f8d2ced.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
n.O @ webpack-adf3ef2afee18f8d2ced.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
t @ webpack-adf3ef2afee18f8d2ced.js:1
(anonymous) @ main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1
Show 7 more frames


main-89e612c37cd79392e22d.js:1 A client-side exception has occurred, see here for more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/client-side-exception-occurred
```

Here is how I implemented it:
In the "Page" component I loaded the scripts in the `<Head>`:

```
import Head from "next/head";
 <Head>
  <script
    async
    src="https://geowidget.easypack24.net/js/sdk-for-javascript.js"
  ></script>
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://geowidget.easypack24.net/css/easypack.css"
  />
</Head>
```

And in the component:

```
componentDidMount() {
....
    this.addInpostMap();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (!this.props.shipmentMethod && prevProps.shipmentMethod) {
      return;
    } else {
      if (this.props.shipmentMethod !== prevProps.shipmentMethod) {
        this.addInpostMap();
      }
    }
  }

  addInpostMap() {
    easyPack.init({});
    var map = easyPack.mapWidget("easypack-map", (point) => {
      // console.log(point);
      this.setState((x) => ({ ...x, paczkomat: point }));
    });
  }


render...
```

On `localhost:3006` everything works great. The scripts load and the logic works.
However when deployed in the live server, that page doesn't load.

Anyone can help to understand and fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing `easyPack` should be accessed via `window.easyPack` inside addInpostMap